ViewModel expose ui state with paging flow
Is there any possibility to expose outside of VM only 1 Flow that contains ScreenUiState and also reviews (paging 3 flow)?
I cannot move reviews flow as val into ScreenUiState because then this makes ScreenUiState as unstable for compose.
(https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#mutating_the_ui_state_from_asynchronous_calls)
class ScreenViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // Reviews Paging Flow.
    val reviews = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 10),
        pagingSourceFactory = { ReviewsPagingSource() }
    ).flow

    // Screen UI State Flow.
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(ScreenUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<ScreenUiState>
        get() = _uiState

}

data class ScreenUiState(
    val header: String? = null,
    val body: String? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
)

data class Review(
    val id: String,
)


class ReviewsPagingSource() : PagingSource<Int, Review>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Review>): Int? {
        ...
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Review> {
        ...
    }
}

